# Graphql: How can get field arguments of a type in resolver?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I use `graphql-tools` library and `makeExecutableSchema` function to make my schema by passing schema and resolver to it

here is my schema:

```
type Trip {
  code: String!
  driver: User!
  vehicle: Vehicle!
  destination: Location!
  passengers(page: Int, count: Int): [User!]!
}
type Query {
  trip(id: String!): Trip
}
```

and here is my resolver:

```
// some imports...
export default {
  Query: {
    async trip(_, { id }, ctx, info) {
      const trip = await Trip.findById(id);
      // const page = ???, count = ???
      // work on fetch data...
      return result;
    },
};
```

how can I get `page` and `count`  which are defined as nested argument for `passengers`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass root parameters in the resolver function of a nested query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094695/how-to-pass-root-parameters-in-the-resolver-function-of-a-nested-query). Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094695/how-to-pass-root-parameters-in-the-resolver-function-of-a-nested-query/48096791#48096791) for that question for a detailed workaround.

Comment: @DanielRearden I need to access a nested argument when using`graphql-tools`, I know it exists in `info` parameter of resolver, but I have no idea how could I parse and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a resolver for the type `Trip`, such as:

```
export default {
  Query: {
    async trip(_, { id }, ctx, info) {
      const trip = await Trip.findById(id);
      // const page = ???, count = ???
      // work on fetch data...
      return result;
    },
  Trip: {
    async passengers(trip, { page, count }, ctx, info) {
      ...
    },
  }
};
```

In GraphQL, it's not the concept of "nested fields of a type", but just combinations of "the type of a field". The `trip` field of type `Query` has the `Trip` type, so when you want to work with the `passengers` field, it should be considered as a field under the `Trip` type, not a nested field of the `Query` type.

Comment: thanks for your replication, it was so helpful.
do you know any way or tool to access the fields(`count` and `page`) on top level? because I want to fetch all data by joining query
I know all data are presented in `info` argument but how can it be parsed

Comment: I think things like Facebook's [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) are tools you might consider. Dataloader can [resolve every individual data request within a batch](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader#batching), and is a different approach of generating a `JOIN` query at top level (which isn't a flexible solution) to load data efficiently.