# graphql: sort by nested field

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have 2 tables:
- Users (id, name, post)
- Posts (id, message, user)

How can I fetch first 10 Posts order by User's name(desc)?

Here's how my schema looks like:

```js
var PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Post",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLInt },
    message: { type: GraphQLString },
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        orderBy: { type: sortType }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        console.info("Post resolve called.");
        return userMap[parent.user];
      }
    }
  })
});

var RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    allPosts: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PostType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        console.info("allPosts resolve called.");
        return postData;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And Query:

```js
{
  allPosts {
    message
    user (orderBy: {field: "name", direction: ASC}) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way, I can call user resolver function before allPosts resolver function? Because, I am trying to fetch 10 users sorted by name and then pass post ids to allPosts resolver.

Answer (score 5):

GraphQL fields are resolved in a top-down fashion. That means `allPosts` is resolved first, then then `message` and `user` fields (simultaneously) and then the `name` field. This has to happen, as the "parent" or root field's resolved value determine's the value that's then passed to the resolver for its children fields as the root value. Information flows from "higher" resolvers to "lower" ones, but not the other way around.

Your `orderBy` argument here probably should be an argument on the `allPosts` field rather than the `user` field. There's two reasons to do that: (1) conceptually, regardless of the sort criteria, you are sorting the Posts returned by `allPosts` -- by convention, it just makes sense to put the sort there; (2) the argument is probably needed by the `allPosts` resolver more than it's needed by the `user` resolver.

To make the above work, you'll probably need to modify how you identify the sort criteria (making `field` a path like `user.name` for example). You may also need "lift" the logic for populating the users up into the `allPosts` resolver. For example:

```
resolve(parentValue, { sortBy: { path, direction } }) {
  const data = postData.map(post => {
    post.user = userMap[post.user]
    return post
  });
  // using lodash
  return orderBy(data, [(post) => get(post, path)], [direction])
}
```

It *is* possible to determine the selection set for other fields inside the request, including the arguments, by parsing the `info` object that's passed in as the fourth parameter to the resolver function. It's a pain though and I don't know if this particular case really justifies doing all that. You can read more about that approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094695/how-to-pass-root-parameters-in-the-resolver-function-of-a-nested-query/48096791#48096791).

Comment: I figured there's no way I can do this. Thanks.!!